# How to get only the visible part of a window (Windows, gdi32, user32, etc)

Tags: java, windows, gdi, visible, winapi

I want to get only the visible part of the window in windows, as a region.

Want to get only the area that is seen by the user.
Programmatically, of course. Here is an example. I have the following window composition:

```
+------------------------------------------+
 |                                          |
 |           +=============+                |
 |           |             |                |
 |           |    A   +--------------------------+
 |           |        |                          |
 |    C      |        |             B            |
 |           |        +--------------------------+
 |           |             |                |
 +-----------|             |----------------+
             |             |
             +-------------+
```

Let's say that I am interested only in window A.
Then what I would need is a handle to a region which would look like this:

```
          +=============+                
          |             |                
          |    A  +-----+
          |       |                          
          |       |                         
          |       +-----+
          |             |                
          |             |
          |             |
          +-------------+
```

Alternatively, I should be able to obtain the region of any other window in the following manner.

So far, I used [this guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030902-00/?p=42693), and I agree that GetClipBox returns 0, 1, 2 or 3 if you have, accordingly,  0 -> Error, 1 for NULLREGION(the resulting rgn is invisible to the user), 2 -> SIMPLEREGION, and 3 for COMPLEXREGION. So, far, I need the complex region.

Master Question: ***But how do I get its coordinates and dimensions*** ?

*(Added Info)*

Is it possible to reconstruct a COMPLEXREGION (That was created by the OS, not me) to simple REGIONS of which it is composed. Feng Yuan suggests you can't:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-126543.html

*(Added Info)*

So, is there a way to find the region of A and **translate it to a PolyPath or a nice geometric figure having the coordinates of its corners** ?

I use JNA (Java) , by the way, but a C# or .VB code solving the same problem would be sufficient.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can enumerate all desktop windows, plus all monitors, and combine their rectangles. I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Note that Windows "lies" about the exact dimensions of windows these days (the Aero window border is slightly bigger than actually reported unless you set a special flag).

Also note that windows can have see-through portions defined by each application (in addition to the see-through window borders you always have under Aero).

You also need to be careful on high-DPI systems where Windows "lies" to your app about coordinates unless you go out of your way to flag it as DPI-aware.

And also note that even an "invisible" window can be visible via the Taskbar, Alt-Tab or Flip3D thumbnails feature of Aero... So, really, on Vista and Windows 7 with DWM enabled, the answer is that your window is potentially always completely visible. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I want to avoid using DWM, for compatibility issues. I know what the issue is with Desktop Window Manager, it is SO nice for a programmer, however I want to cover also XP boxes and also ones that have DWM disabled.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use DWM for anything; just pointing out a bunch of issues you have to worry about if DWM is enabled (if you want to support it in addition to XP etc.)

Comment: Well some code would have been nicer, or even an assurance it can be done, because I start to doubt it is possible on XP boxes or machines not running DWM.

Comment: Just call EnumWindows ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx ) to enumerate all the top-level windows. They will be enumerated in depth order so any you get before your window will be on top of it and if they overlap will obscure it. Then call EnumDisplayMonitors ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28VS.85%29.aspx ) to get the rectangles for all monitors on the system to test that your window is actually on a screen. Both of those APIs work on XP and without DWM. Not sure where you got the idea that DWM was required for what I suggested.

Comment: If I call EnumWindows I can indeed get all the windows sorted by Z - order. However, for those who have higher z-order than mine, I do not know if they have any overlapping part with it. I can actually check if they do. And if some do, what then :) I can't get the intersection of the regions. My question is how to create a complex figure having the shape and size of the region. Because I can't do anything with a region.

Comment: GetWindowRect, CreateRectRgn, CombineRgn

Comment: Any suggestions how to combine those calls? I get the window rectangle with GetWindowRect, but from then on it is a lost battle. Listing some functions that do something is not even an attempt of a solution and I am getting more and more convinced it is impossible to achieve my task on XP. Combine rgn would work if I knew the dimensions of the regions of which the visible part of my window is composed. However, I do not and here is the essence of the problem: "there is no programmatic way of obtaining the regions that only the visible part of a window is composed of"

Comment: Have you even looked at the APIs I gave you? Combining them is trivial: EnumWindows gives you each window on the desktop. GetWindowRect gets you the rectangle for a window. CreateRectRgn gets you a region for a rectangle. CombineRgn lets you combine two regions (e.g. to see where they do or do not overlap) and returns a third region which is the result (that you can then combine further). What's the missing link you're not seeing here? I've given you the ingredients; I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: When I obtain a COMPLEXRGN, it is impossible to obtain its coordinates to be used by other program. Even the gdi creator says it is impossible. Thus, even if you wanted, you couldn't have written the code for me. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small function which computes the visible region of any window.
Pass window handle to this function and It will return visible region of the window.

```
HRGN GetVisibleRegion(HWND hwnd)
{   
    //Store the region of window hwnd
    RECT hwndRect={0,0,0,0};
    ::GetWindowRect(hwnd,&hwndRect);
    HRGN rgn=::CreateRectRgn(hwndRect.left,hwndRect.top,hwndRect.right,hwndRect.bottom);


    //HWND hParentWnd=::GetParent(hwnd);
    HWND hParentWnd=::GetAncestor(hwnd,GA_PARENT);
    HWND hChildWnd=hwnd;
    //until we reaches desktop window
    while(hChildWnd!=NULL && hChildWnd!=GetDesktopWindow())
    {
        HWND topWnd=::GetTopWindow(hParentWnd);
        do
        {
            if(topWnd==hChildWnd) 
            {
                break;
            }
            RECT topWndRect={0,0,0,0}; ::GetWindowRect(topWnd,&topWndRect);
            RECT tempRect={0,0,0,0};
            //Other window overlapping with hwnd
            if(::IsWindowVisible(topWnd) && !::IsIconic(topWnd) && IntersectRect(&tempRect,&topWndRect,&hwndRect)!=0) 
            {
                HRGN topWndRgn=::CreateRectRgn(topWndRect.left,topWndRect.top,topWndRect.right,topWndRect.bottom);
                ::CombineRgn(rgn,rgn,topWndRgn,RGN_DIFF);
                ::RealDeleteObject(topWndRgn);
            }
            topWnd = GetNextWindow(topWnd, TWO);

        }while(topWnd!=NULL);
        hChildWnd=hParentWnd;
        //hParentWnd=::GetParent(hParentWnd);
        hParentWnd=::GetAncestor(hParentWnd,GA_PARENT);
    }   
    return rgn;
}
```